# How can I get data from service in Angular interceptor?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-providers

I want to add my authentication token in the request header in my **auth.interceptor.ts** and I'm keeping the authentication token value in my **auth.service.ts**.

Here's **auth.interceptor.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('intercept', request);
        const authReq = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set(this.authService.getAuthenticationKey(), this.authService.getAuthenticationToken())});
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

and here's part of **auth.service.ts**

```js
...
public getAuthenticationToken(): string {
    return this.authenticationToken;
}

public getAuthenticationKey(): string {
    return this.authenticationKey;
}
...
```

And here's my **app.module.ts**

```js
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useFactory: (router: Router, authService: AuthService) => {
            return new AuthInterceptor(router, authService);
        },
        multi: true,
        deps: [Router]
    }
],
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAuthenticationKey')

What is the problem?

Comment: Add `AuthService` in `deps`. `deps: [Router, AuthService]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `AuthService` into dependencies (`deps`). As the factory function has access to `AuthService`, you need to inject it into the factory provider.

```js
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useFactory: (router: Router, authService: AuthService) => {
            return new AuthInterceptor(router, authService);
        },
        multi: true,
        deps: [Router, AuthService]
    }
],
```

---

### References

[Using factory providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-factory-providers)